# How to run SQL query in visual Studio Code

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-code

I recently stepped into the wonderful and confusing world of programming, SQL and all the good stuff.

Since I am still beginning my journey I am kind of stuck with lots of small things.
For example I set up a server, uploaded a CSV onto it and had the intention of writing SQL queries to get used to SQL (and later Python)

I'd like to write my query in Visual Studio Code & see what comes out of it.
But unfortunately I am unable to create an output.
Is there a possibility to write & run query in VSC? Or do I need to address this process different?

Thank you very much in advance!

[image: Preview of my screen]

Answer (score 2):

You could use an extension that allows you to connect to a local/remote database and execute SQL commands through VSC. I've used [Database Client](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cweijan.vscode-database-client2) in the past, and was satisfied with the result. It could also format `.sql` files and allows you to run queries from straight from a file as well.